# Upload file via AWS Gateway Api through Lambda to S3

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, boto3

i want to upload a file to an aws S3 Bucket but i need to manipulate the file before the upload via a lambda function.
So i want to make an Gateway Api with a HTTP-PUT method which uses lambda to change the file and upload it to s3.
Is this possible? Can I upload large files without problems?

Answer (score 3):

You will have the limitation of upload file size.

Payload size is 10MB.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/limits.html

> Cloudfront -- S3 -- (Trigger) -- Lambda (Process and Save) -- S3

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thats sad, guess i will do it like in this article https://sookocheff.com/post/api/uploading-large-payloads-through-api-gateway/